# SQL Server stored procedure oDate as a parameter not recognized

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

How can we pass the date (data type `DateTime`) in the execution command to run a stored procedure?

Here is the code snippet.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[datefiltered]
    @months_margin int, 
    @oDate         datetime
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.table20
    WHERE date = oDate

    -- more code...
END
```

I am trying to execute this stored procedure using `GETDATE()` function or even pass date and time as a string but it's not working.

```
exec datefiltered 23 getDate()
```

Comment: Why do you have parameters on your Procedure in the first place, you don't use them in the query at all; you just check to see if the column `[date]` has the same value as the **column** `oDate`. As for why, parameters passed to a procedure must be literal or a variable. You'll need to assign the value (`GETDATE()`) to a variable first, and then pass that to the procedure.

Comment: Also, parameters need to be delimited; there should be a comma between `23` and the next parameter's value.

Comment: I am using param in my code but keep it hidden just to simplify it. also added the delimiter

Comment: Hint: `where [date] = @oDate` (`@oDate` is the parameter, `oDate` is a column name).

Comment: Your code is unlikely to work anyway, as `GETDATE()` includes the time. you probably mean `date >= CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AND date < DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to apply date filter, you don't need to pass datetime value. You can convert to DATE datatype for equality.

```sql
 select * from dbo.table20
     where date = CAST(@oDate AS DATE)
```

Also, if you are just passing GETDATE() as default, you can keep getdate as default value, as given below:

```sql
Alter procedure [dbo].[datefiltered]
      @months_margin   int, 
      @oDate           datetime = null 
AS 
Begin 

IF @oDate IS NULL
BEGIN
SET @oDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
END
```

When you call the procedure with default value, you don't need to pass parameter value for it.

```sql
exec datefiltered 23 -- getdate() filter is applied automatically
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[datefiltered]
    @months_margin int, 
    @oDate         datetime
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.table20
    WHERE date = CAST(@oDate AS DATE)

    -- more code...
END
```

Executing this stored procedure:

```
exec datefiltered 23, '2010-02-30'
```